# How does the getModifiers() method calculate the value for multiple modifiers?

Tags: java

The Java Doc for [getModifiers()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#getModifiers%28%29) is as follows:

> int getModifiers()
>
> Returns the Java language modifiers for the member or constructor represented by this Member, as an integer. The Modifier class should be used to decode the modifiers in the integer.

and Java Docs also provide the [list of different modifiers and their corresponding int values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html):

> public static final int    ABSTRACT        1024
>
> public static final int    FINAL           16
>
> public static final int    INTERFACE       512
>
> public static final int    NATIVE          256
>
> public static final int    PRIVATE         2
>
> public static final int    PROTECTED       4
>
> public static final int    PUBLIC          1
>
> public static final int    STATIC          8
>
> public static final int    STRICT          2048
>
> public static final int    SYNCHRONIZED    32
>
> public static final int    TRANSIENT       128
>
> public static final int    VOLATILE        64

For a single modifier it is very straightforward for getModifiers(). It simply returns the constant value corresponding to the modifier (e.g. when I declare one class as ***public final*** and call the getModifiers() it returns ***17***).

```
System.out.println("modifierValue:" + MyClass.class.getModifiers());
```

Output is:

```
17
```

However, I can't quite understand how it would work for multiple modifiers. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Read about bit masks. The value is basically Modifier<1> + Modifier<2> + ... + Modifier<n>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## TL;DR: It adds them together to form a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

To understand this you need to understand how binary works, this is similar to decimal - lets start there:

```
 1    - public
 10   - static
 100  - final
```

So, what does `101` mean? It must be `public final` because there is no other way in the decimal system to make "one hundred and one" except with a single `100` and a single `1`.

Now extend this to binary:

```
1 - public
2 - private
4 - protected
8 - static
```

So what does `9` mean? Well, as with the decimal system there is only one (correct) way to make `9` in binary - one `8` and one `1`.

Now we use what we call a bitfield, `9` in binary is:

```
1001
```

To verify, **write some code**!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = 9;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

Now, with the decimal system we would divide by `10` repeatedly and check the right most digit (least significant). With binary this process is identical, except we divide by `2` - this is known as bit shifting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = 9;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    i >>= 1;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    i >>= 1;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
    i >>= 1;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

Output:

```
1001
100
10
1
```

So, if I know that `private` is the 2<sup>1</sup> value, and we know how many bits we have, all just need to shift the right number of digits and take the modulo with `2`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = 9;
    i >>= 2;
    System.out.println(i%2);
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

So we basically use the `1` and `0` values that make up a number in binary to number to store booleans.

So take this example into the read world:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Method method = App.class.getMethod("myMethod");
    final int modifiers = method.getModifiers();
    System.out.println(modifiers);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(modifiers));
}

public strictfp synchronized static final void myMethod() {

}
```

Output:

```
2105
100000111001
```

So we can see we have:

2<sup>0</sup>   = 1    - `true`
2<sup>1</sup>   = 2    - `false`
2<sup>2</sup>   = 4    - `false`
2<sup>3</sup>   = 8    - `true`
2<sup>4</sup>   = 16   - `true`
2<sup>5</sup>   = 32   - `true`
2<sup>7</sup>   = 64   - `false`
2<sup>8</sup>   = 128  - `false`
2<sup>9</sup>   = 256  - `false`
2<sup>10</sup>  = 512  - `false`
2<sup>11</sup>  = 1024 - `false`
2<sup>12</sup>  = 2048 - `true`